# How this arrow function doesn't give any error?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I just run up into some code and then I did a test and found something I don't understand.

```
hey(
  () => {},
  () => {
    foo: "bar";
  }
);
```

Why the following syntax is a valid syntax? In the first argument, I can understand, because is an empty function scope, but in the second argument, how it doesn't give me an error?

If it's returning a object, it should be `({...})` and don't accept `;` at the end, so this means that the second argument isn't an object.

If it isn't an object, what is it? Why it isn't a syntax error?

What black javascript magic is happening here?

Here is an example on [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-cdn-lpmbs) and it doens't give me any syntax error.

## Edit

I just found some other weird thing.

```
hey(
  () => {},
  () => {
    "bar"; // without foo:
  }
);
```

How this doesn't give any error?

Comment: after your edit: why would that give an error? You're allowed to have a string that doesn't do anything. It's meaningless, but no reason to error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you skip the `()`, it's interpreted as a [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

```js
() => {
  foo: "bar";
}
```

If add another property, you can see the error clearly

```js
() => {
  foo: "bar",
  baz: ''
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The second argument ISN'T an object. It's a function. The second argument is basically equivalent to saying

```
function() {
   foo: "bar";
}
```

Which in fact doesn't error, despite looking like it should

If you want an arrow function to return an object immediately, the syntax is

```
() => ({foo:'bar'})
```

Comment: What is that? How can it do `foo: "bar";` without any error?

Comment: @Vencovsky no idea, I think it's meaningless but not an error.

Comment: @Vencovsky I edited my answer to show how you'd return an object from an arrow function

Comment: well.. that doesn't explain much